# how do `typescript` work with `Code Spliting` of Webpack 2

Tags: typescript, webpack-2

`webpack 2` use `import('xx').then()` to split code. But use `import()` in ts is invalid.

any examples to show how to use `import()` with webpack 2 and ts ?

Comment: see [this issue](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/352)

Comment: which Typescript version are you using? i guess Version "2.4.1" understands "import()"